# No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientaton' in package 'android' activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android

I encountered this error while debugging my "hello world" App as found in the Get Started Android Development tutorial. Here is my full activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientaton="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

I really need some help with this one considering I believe it is keystroke for keystroke as it appears in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled orientation - orientat **i** on, not `orientaton`.

Comment: @user2342919 - it is always something small - glad I could help! One thing that will help in the future is to use auto-complete whenever you can - in Eclipse, use Ctrl+Space to autocomplete an XML tag.

Comment: Just loaded my first working app to my Galaxy Tab! I'm total stoked.